# Transferring a Vector3 variable from one script (WayPointPositioner) to another and change it into a transform (Walking)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the Vector3 wayPointPosition to my other script called Walking and changing it into the Transform target. My troubles lie in the fact that I'm trying to grab this dynamic variable from WayPointPositioner (it changes depending on what object is clicked in the stage and whether the player overlaps with this waypoint) and import and use it in another script.

Below is the code I'm using.

**WayPointPositioner**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WayPointPositioner : MonoBehaviour {

public Vector3 wayPointPosition = Vector3.zero;
private bool checkPlayerWaypointCollision;

void Start()
{

}

void OnTriggerStay2D (Collider2D other) 
{
    // Check if collision is occuring with player character.
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        checkPlayerWaypointCollision = true;
    }
    else
    {
        checkPlayerWaypointCollision = false;
    }

}

//Check if object is clicked
void OnMouseDown () 
{

    // If its the player, then return a new position for the player to move to for walking
    // Else debug that its not so
        if (checkPlayerWaypointCollision == false)
        {

            Debug.Log ("Object not colliding and retrieving position");
            Debug.Log (wayPointPosition);
            Debug.Log (gameObject.name);

            wayPointPosition = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, 10);
            wayPointPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(wayPointPosition);

        }
        else
        {

            Debug.Log ("Object is colliding, no movement needed");

        }

}

}
```

**Walking**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Walking : MonoBehaviour {


public Transform target;
public WayPointPositioner wayPointPosition;

public bool walkingAnimation = false;
private Animator anim;

void Awake ()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    wayPointPosition = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Waypoint").GetComponent<WayPointPositioner> ();

}


void Start () 
{

}


void Update () 
{
    Debug.Log ("This is in Walking, WPP =" + wayPointPosition);
}
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to import the wayPointPosition from the seperate class which is attached to the gameobjects called "Waypoint" (In my current layout those are empty objects with circle colliders to check if they have been clicked). However when I run this, I am not getting my Vector, but I'm getting the name of the last waypoint in the hierarchy (I have currently 6 waypoints which can be clicked) and not a Vector.

I hope someone is able to help me / point out my mistake. I'm still learning C# so I might've made a strange / odd assumption which isn't working.

Kind regards,

Veraduxxz.

Comment: Changed a little something to try it out but it doesn't seem to be working. I looked into the Unity manual and found a bit of code like this:     wayPointPosition = transform.Find ("Waypoint").GetComponent<WayPointPositioner> ().wayPointPosition; Now, this DOES retrieve my variable (it recognizes the Vector3 of wayPointPosition in my Walking script) but it gives the error that I cannot translate WayPointPosition to a Vector3 (which would be right)

Comment: new comment: removed the "Public WayPointPositioner wayPointPosition;" and added .wayPointPosition at the end of GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Waypoint").GetComponent<WayPointPositioner> (); that seemed to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like invoking `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Waypoint").GetComponent<WayPointPositioner>();` retrieves a component from the game object which matches the specified tag, as well as a type argument T which derives from `MonoBehavior`.

Calling this should actually give you an instance of your `WayPointPositioner` class, which you can then pass to whichever methods you want, and interact with its `Vector3` however you would like.

Comment: That's what I did. But when I did it like that, it would only give me the name of the gameobject in question. However adding .wayPointPosition at the end of your first part fixed the problem. I can now retrieve the variable from the waypoints and use them in walking. A new problem occurs however where it's not updating properly and only taking the 6th waypoint again as a 'new' variable from wayPointPosition (it doesn't do this when I ask for the variable in WayPointPositioner, it recognizes the position of the other objects).

Comment: Well... yeah. That whole long command gives you a reference to object, so adding `.wayPointPosition` works, because you're referring to a *variable* that belongs to the *object* that it retrieved.